# RxJava: Invoking multiple unrelated methods sequentially

Tags: java, rx-java

I use RxJava in my project and I have a situation where 2 methods are called one after the other and both return void. Each of these methods internally use RxJava.

Pseudo:

```
void sendMsg_1() {
...
//Fetch data from DB using RxJava to send message to client.
..
}

void sendMsg_2() {
...
Uses RxJava to send message to client.
..
}
```

Invoking code:

```
sendMsg_1();
sendMsg_2();
```

Practically, sendMsg_2 is faster and client gets it before sendMsg_1 sends his msg. This is not good for me and I would like output of Msg1 be sent before Msg2.

How to do it?

Should I artificially return dummy observable just so I can use .flatMap as follow:

```
sendMsg_1()
.flatMap(msgObj-> { 
    return sendMsg_2();
}).subscribe();
```

Is there a better way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to emit void methods the rxJava's way:

```
public rx.Completable func_A() {
    return Completable.create(subscriber -> {
        // func_A logic
        if(ok) subscriber.onCompleted();
        else subscriber.onError(throwable);
    });
}

func_A()
.doOnCompleted(() -> func_B())
.subscribe();
```

If it helps anyone...enjoy :-)

Comment: only problem with that is that you don't get a notification that func_B was completed.

Comment: what do you mean? What kind of notification?

Comment: Question, How can I emit an Observable that will be called only after all Completable's were finished? I tried using: 'endWith()' but it didn't yield correct results.

Comment: use `Completable.concat` with your 2 completables, or concatWith on the first one

Comment: and then what? How to emit the Observable?

Comment: concat\concatWith are only for 'Completable' - I need to emit 'Observable'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108124/discussion-between-shvalb-and-njzk2).